# Make one commit from two

Tags: git, bitbucket

I forgot to use amend commit, and I created second commit in remote branch with same name.

```
4effxgg ISSUE-434
f45fsfg ISSUE-434
```

Is any simple way how to fix that and create one commit? Thanks.

Comment: `git rebase`­­­

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i <branch>` (interactive); squash one and pick the other.

Remember to specify the branch you're rebasing onto.

### Note

As pointed out by John Zwinck, pick the earliest commit and squash the later commits.

Comment: Specifically, pick the earlier and squash/fixup the later.

Answer (score 1):

use `git rebase -i` (interactive git rebase).

In your case, you can do the following:

```
git rebase -i 4effxgg
```

It will open this page:

```
pick 4effxgg ISSUE-434
pick f45fsfg ISSUE-434
```

change the 2nd `pick` to `f`, like the following:

```
pick 4effxgg ISSUE-434
f f45fsfg ISSUE-434
```

Then save the page. It will merge the 2 commits. Here is a [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/todgru/7cff3962e76e1360cc2c) you can refer to.

Comment: I do that ... locally I have just one commit with all changes .. but when I try push it to remote I got message everything up to date and changes aren't reflected on remote repository

Comment: It shouldn't happen. If it's saying that everything is up-to-date, it probably is. It might be that you are looking at a diff place and pushing at a diff place. Try checking that.

Comment: @DenisStephanov why did you un-accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you may run `git reset HEAD~2`. This will effectively checkout the commit before these 2 commits while keeping the changes you made in these 2 commits(as unstaged). from here you may `git add .` and `git commit -m'your new message'`.

The tricky thing is with synching the remote. If you are working on a feature branch that only you work on then you may `git push --force` without any troubles. On the other hand if you are working on a branch together with other people that may have already pulled these 2 commits that you previously pushed to the remote, than the safe thing to do is just leave it like that, don't fix this "2 commits mistake" and don't cause anyone any additional problem.